# How to create facerecognigation mobile security lock system programeticaly using opencv

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am creating one leave management Application in android,
employees in and out time will be calculated on face detection,
it means one or more face store in database and compare the camera will be tack photos user face is detected the save to temp. and compare with saved images.

any have idea to how can compare images ? useing openCV ?

Answer (score 0):

**Image Comaresion:**
OpenCV provides various methods to compare the faces
here it is.
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

To create an app for FR,  you will need to develop two component server and  app.

**1. Server: **
You can create a server using Java/python, and integrate OpenCV at server side.
You need two scripts at server side one is for Face enrollment/training and other is for face recognition.

**2. App**
You apps will treat as client, the app sends the camera frame to server  for enrollment or FR process, the server will apply the image processing on that frame and returns the result to the app

To transfer images at real time, you can use the Socket connections